# How to run and install poetry in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have an issue about the permission in lambda function.
I am using cdkv2 deploy, deploy to lambda function by dockerfile and add dependencies to aws layer.
But , in def handler, I am using

```
os.system('poetry run pytest test/'}
```

It can not work and log the message :

Creating virtualenv automation-lUCKSD9c-py3.11 in /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs

[image]

Are there any solutions for this issue?

Comment: It appears that poetry is detecting that it needs to install libraries, and then it is failing because the file system is read-only. You should be running `poetry install` in your Dockerfile as part of the build.

Comment: Yes, I ran poetry install in dockerfile, but, I still got this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is when running the command `poetry run` it is creating a virtual environment within the file system of the lambda container but you can only write to the `/tmp` in Lambdas, so you need to configure the virtualenv to be created inside of `/tmp`:

```
poetry config virtualenvs.path /path/to/cache/directory/virtualenvs
```

Or you can choose to not create one if you'd like:

```
poetry config virtualenvs.create false --local
```

Or even set an environment variable that will tell poetry where to create the virtualenv, refer to the [poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/) for more details on the config command.